# What is _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault?

Tags: python, python-3.x, profiling, perf, python-internals

When I'm profiling with perf `_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault` is at the top for CPU usage.

But I don't know what it is. How can I avoid this function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are running your Python program in the CPython [interpreter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_(computing)#Bytecode_interpreters). While the Python code gets translated to bytecode, this bytecode doesn't run on the CPU itself but is executed by a program itself. The core of this interpreter program is `_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault`. Since `perf` profiles the instructions of the CPU, it only sees this function being executed all the time.

In order to understand which *Python* functions take up most of the time, you need to use a native [Python performance analysis tool](https://stackoverflow.com/q/582336/620382).

Comment: In 3.12 Python has some support for the perf profiler that goes beyond that function: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/perf_profiling.html